# Reading XML files with DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, nlp

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
  <source />
  <date />
  <key />
  <document>
    <id>AIMed_d30</id>
    <passage>
      <offset>0</offset>
      <text>Isolation of human delta-catenin and its binding specificity with presenilin 1. We screened proteins for interaction with presenilin (PS) 1, and cloned the full-length cDNA of human delta-catenin, which encoded 1225 amino acids. Yeast two-hybrid assay, GST binding assay and immunoprecipitation demonstrated that delta-catenin interacted with a hydrophilic loop region in the endoproteolytic C-terminal fragment of PS1, but not with that of PS-2. These results suggest that PS1 and PS2 partly differ in function. PS1 loop fragment containing the pathogenic mutation retained the binding ability. We also found another armadillo-protein, p0071, interacted with PS1.</text>
      <annotation id="T1">
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">protein</infon>
        <location length="13" offset="19" />
        <text>delta-catenin</text>
      </annotation>
      <annotation id="T3">
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">protein</infon>
        <location length="17" offset="122" />
        <text>presenilin (PS) 1</text>
      </annotation>
      <annotation id="T2">
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">protein</infon>
        <location length="12" offset="66" />
        <text>presenilin 1</text>
      </annotation>
      <relation id="R4">
        <infon key="relation type">Interaction</infon>
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">Relation</infon>
        <node role="Arg1" refid="T12" />
        <node role="Arg2" refid="T13" />
      </relation>
      <relation id="R2">
        <infon key="relation type">Interaction</infon>
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">Relation</infon>
        <node role="Arg1" refid="T3" />
        <node role="Arg2" refid="T4" />
      </relation>
      <relation id="R3">
        <infon key="relation type">Interaction</infon>
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">Relation</infon>
        <node role="Arg1" refid="T5" />
        <node role="Arg2" refid="T6" />
      </relation>
      -
      <relation id="R1">
        <infon key="relation type">Interaction</infon>
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">Relation</infon>
        <node role="Arg1" refid="T1" />
        <node role="Arg2" refid="T2" />
      </relation>
    </passage>
  </document>
</collection>
```

but when I use DOM for reading this XML file, I have some problems. For example, for the `annotation` tag, it has 8 item tags in it, but when I print the result, it becomes 10 or more. And for the `relation` tag, it doesn't work right. This is my Java code:

```
public class XMLRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        try{
            File fXmlFile = new File("D:/THESIS/DataSet/Newfolder/Newfolder/aimed_bioc2.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("document");

            System.out.println("OK----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                file1_Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                file1_
                    file1_System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                file1_
                    file1_if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                        System.out.println("id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());

                        //                    NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("passage");
                        //                    for(int i=0; i< nList2.getLength(); i++)
                        //                    {
                        System.out.println("\toffset : " +  eElement.getElementsByTagName("offset").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println("\ttext: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("text").item(0).getTextContent());                        
                        System.out.println("----------------------------");

                        NodeList nList3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("annotation");                       
                        for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList3.getLength(); temp2++) {   
                            Node nNode2 = nList3.item(temp2);tln("\n\n");
                            if(nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  
                            {
                                Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
                                System.out.println("\tannotation id : " + eElement2.getAttribute("id"));

                                NodeList nList4=doc.getElementsByTagName("infon");

                                Node nNode3=nList4.item(0);
                                Node nNode4=nList4.item(1);

                                Element eElement3= (Element) nNode3;                                             
                                Element eElement4= (Element) nNode4;
                                System.out.println("\t\tinfon key : " + eElement3.getAttribute("key")
                                        +",   infon : " +eElement.getElementsByTagName("infon").item(0).getTextContent());
                                System.out.println("\t\tinfon key : " + eElement4.getAttribute("key")
                                        + ",   infon : " +eElement.getElementsByTagName("infon").item(1).getTextContent());        

                                NodeList nList5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("location");                                                           
                                Node nNode5=nList5.item(temp2);

                                Element eElement5=(Element) nNode5;
                                System.out.println("\t\tLocation Lenght : " +eElement5.getAttribute("length")
                                        +"   ,Location offset : " + eElement5.getAttribute("offset"));

                                System.out.println("\t\tannotation text : "+ eElement2.getElementsByTagName("text").item(0).getTextContent());
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("----------------------------");

                        NodeList nList6 = doc.getElementsByTagName("relation");                       
                        for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nList6.getLength(); temp3++) {   
                            Node nNode6 = nList6.item(temp3);tln("\n\n");
                            if(nNode6.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  
                            {
                                Element eElement6 = (Element) nNode6;
                                System.out.println("\tRelation id : " + eElement6.getAttribute("id"));
                                Node nNode14=nList6.item(0);
                                Element eElement14=(Element) nNode14;
                                NodeList nList7=doc.getElementsByTagName("infon");
                                for(int temp5 = 0; temp5<nList7.getLength(); temp5++){
                                    Node nNode7=nList7.item(temp5);
                                    Node nNode8=nList7.item(1);
                                    Node nNode9=nList7.item(2);
                                    Element eElement7= (Element) nNode7;                                             
                                    Element eElement8= (Element) nNode8;
                                    Element eElement9= (Element) nNode9;
                                    System.out.println("\t\tinfon key : " + eElement7.getAttribute("key")
                                            +"    ,infon : " +eElement6.getElementsByTagName("infon").item(0).getTextContent());}
                                    System.out.println("\n\n");

                                    NodeList nList8 = doc.getElementsByTagName("node"); 
                                    for(int temp4=0; temp4<nList8.getLength(); temp4++)
                                    {
                                        Node nNode12 = nList8.item(temp4);
                                        Element eElement12 = (Element) nNode12;

                                        System.out.println("\t\tNode Role : " +eElement12.getAttribute("role")
                                                +"   ,refid : " + eElement12.getAttribute("refid"));
                                    }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please fix your XML to be valid, since the `-` before the root element is invalid. All the extra `-` characters are probably wrong. Also format the XML for **human readability**, since you are asking humans (that would be us) for help. And the XML is *not* a "snippet".

Comment: Thanks for your help... I copied them, and didn't see the - marks. :)

Comment: and about snippet, I don't know how to handle it... I didn't add xml as snippet!!! but after that I saw it .

Comment: I fixed the snippet and code indentation, but to make this a good question, you have to reduce this by a lot - it should be a [mcve], and now it's a pretty large code dump. Also, "doesn't work" is not a good problem description: what happens exactly? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: actually in relation part I don't see any result.. empty!! but I think at least it has to show something

Answer (score 0):

When your program handle child elements, `doc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)` will return match nodes of whole document. If this is not want you want, you shall review the code and fix it. For example:

```
NodeList nList6 = doc.getElementsByTagName("relation");                       
for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nList6.getLength(); temp3++) {   
    Node nNode6 = nList6.item(temp3);           
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    if(nNode6.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  
    {
        Element eElement6 = (Element) nNode6;
        System.out.println("\tRelation id : " + eElement6.getAttribute("id"));
        Node nNode14=nList6.item(0);
        Element eElement14=(Element) nNode14;
        //NodeList nList7=doc.getElementsByTagName("infon");
        //Correct call for getting all descendant elements of *eElement6*
        NodeList nList7=eElement6.getElementsByTagName("infon");
         //...
     }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of usage is a good demonstration of how org.w3c.dom.* code usage can quickly become difficult to read. Parsing to a typed class structure is one way of avoiding it.

Or, if you can use Java 8 my library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics#xml-dynamics) may provide a more readable way, along with null-safety & more descriptive error reporting.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("D:/THESIS/DataSet/Newfolder/Newfolder/aimed_bioc2.xml");
XmlDynamic xml = new XmlDynamic(new FileReader(fXmlFile));

xml.get("collection").children()
    .filter(hasElementName("document"))
    .forEach(document -> {
        System.out.println("id : " + document.get("id").asString());
        System.out.println("\toffset : " +  document.get("passage|offset").asString());
        System.out.println("\ttext: " + document.get("passage|text").asString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        Dynamic passage = document.get("passage");
        passage.children()
            .filter(hasElementName("annotation"))
            .forEach(annotation -> {
                System.out.println("\tannotation id : " + annotation.get("id").asString());

                annotation.children()
                    .filter(hasElementName("infon"))
                    .forEach(infon -> {
                        System.out.printf("\t\tinfon key : %s,   infon : %s%n",
                            infon.get("key").asString(), infon.asString());
                    });

                System.out.printf("\t\tlocation Length : %s,   location offset : %s%n",
                    annotation.get("location|length").asString(), annotation.get("location|offset").asString());

                System.out.println("\t\tannotation text : "+ annotation.get("text").asString());
            });

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        passage.children()
            .filter(hasElementName("relation"))
            .forEach(relation -> {
                System.out.println("\trelation id : " + relation.get("id").asString());

                relation.children()
                    .filter(hasElementName("infon"))
                    .forEach(infon -> {
                        System.out.printf("\t\tinfon key : %s,   infon : %s%n",
                            infon.get("key").asString(), infon.asString());
                    });

                relation.children()
                    .filter(hasElementName("node"))
                    .forEach(node -> {
                        System.out.printf("\t\tnode role : %s,   refid : %s%n",
                            node.get("role").asString(), node.get("refid").asString());
                    });
            });
    });
```

Output:

```
id : AIMed_d30
    offset : 0
    text: Isolation of human delta-catenin and its binding specificity with presenilin 1. We screened proteins for interaction with presenilin (PS) 1, and cloned the full-length cDNA of human delta-catenin, which encoded 1225 amino acids. Yeast two-hybrid assay, GST binding assay and immunoprecipitation demonstrated that delta-catenin interacted with a hydrophilic loop region in the endoproteolytic C-terminal fragment of PS1, but not with that of PS-2. These results suggest that PS1 and PS2 partly differ in function. PS1 loop fragment containing the pathogenic mutation retained the binding ability. We also found another armadillo-protein, p0071, interacted with PS1.
----------------------------
    annotation id : T1
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : protein
        location Length : 13,   location offset : 19
        annotation text : delta-catenin
    annotation id : T3
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : protein
        location Length : 17,   location offset : 122
        annotation text : presenilin (PS) 1
    annotation id : T2
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : protein
        location Length : 12,   location offset : 66
        annotation text : presenilin 1
----------------------------
    relation id : R4
        infon key : relation type,   infon : Interaction
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : Relation
        node role : Arg1,   refid : T12
        node role : Arg2,   refid : T13
    relation id : R2
        infon key : relation type,   infon : Interaction
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : Relation
        node role : Arg1,   refid : T3
        node role : Arg2,   refid : T4
    relation id : R3
        infon key : relation type,   infon : Interaction
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : Relation
        node role : Arg1,   refid : T5
        node role : Arg2,   refid : T6
    relation id : R1
        infon key : relation type,   infon : Interaction
        infon key : file,   infon : ann
        infon key : type,   infon : Relation
        node role : Arg1,   refid : T1
        node role : Arg2,   refid : T2
```

see https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics#xml-dynamics